# App installation failed : This application does not support this device’s CPU type

Tags: ios11, xcode9.2

I get an error when I try to load my application on iPhone7 in Xcode9.2. version of Iphone7 is ios11.0.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can check in your project is that you have selected 'Standard Architectures' in Project's Build Settings. As in below image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case 'Standard Architectures' in Project's Build Settings was set, yet I was getting this error. So the thing that fixed it for me was changing the value of **"Mach-O Type"** to **Executable**[image]